# SQL SELECT from ordered column

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a large sqlite3 database of prime numbers with `.schema` as below:

```
CREATE TABLE Primes(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, prime);
```

I'm trying to improve lookup speed for the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM Primes WHERE prime < SOME_NUMBER ORDER BY id ASC;
```

As I know that both the `id` and `prime` columns are ordered, the query should be able to stop immediately after a `prime >= SOME_NUMBER`is found. I understand why it doesn't since sqlite3 has no way of knowing that `prime` is sorted.

1. Are there any alterations I can perform on the table to have sqlite3 know that the `prime` column is sorted? (Note that the database is regularly expanded and write speed is important, i.e. index might not be a good option from what I've [read](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_create_index.asp))
2. Are there any keywords I could include in my query to have sqlite3 stop after it finds a `prime >= SOME_NUMBER`?

Answer (score 1):

Here are the considerations:

1. If SOME_NUMBER is relatively big (the query will return a large chunk of the rows), an index won't be of much help.
2. If You have many queries where SOME_NUMBER is relatively small (the query will return a small chunk of the rows), an index will have a huge benefit since the other option is to scan the full table again and again and again.
3. In any case, having an index on a table (and you already got one - `id`) comes with performance penalty for DML (Data Manipulation Language) operations, including Inserts.

If the answer for (2) is 'True' -
Since I estimate an insert of 100K values to take less than a second(*1) and a full scan of the table with 2G values to take around 3 minutes, I would  recommend to create the index.

```
create unique index Primes_un_prime on Primes (prime);
```

Please notice that this actually a covering index (containning both 'prime' and 'id') 
https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#rowid

---

*1

```
insert into Primes (prime)
with t(i) as (select 1 union all select i+1 from t where i < 100000)
select i from t
```

Comment: Ordering by prime results in the results being shown after the entire column is indexed (some seconds of waiting time. My original query has the same waiting time, but after the results are shown). As the write to read ratio is a few 100000 to 1 I'm a bit sceptical to adding an index as I've read that it might slow INSERT operations down (see the question).If you still believe these suggestions may be beneficial, would you mind elaborating a bit?

Comment: 200Million/2Billion+ (Can double check in an hour or so)

Comment: And the 2nd question?

Comment: Yes, I need id in the db and the result but not necessarily ordered by in this instance

Comment: The ORDER BY id is actually a remnant of how the query used to look and could be omitted in my question-query without impact

Comment: Do you need to return the id?

Answer (score 0):

Making lookups on `prime` fast requires that this column is indexed.

Instead of adding an index to that column, you could use a [clustered index](http://www.sqlite.org/withoutrowid.html) with `prime` as the first column of the key:

```
CREATE TABLE Primes(
    prime,
    id INTEGER,
    PRIMARY KEY (prime)        
) WITHOUT ROWID;
```

This makes lookups or sorting on `id` slow.
If the primes are not unique, you need to add `id` to the PK.

Comment: In addition we won't get generated IDs